# Adding an element to the end of linkedlist

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a function headinsert that is working fin. That adds element at the "head".
But I am trying to make a function endinsert that adds an element at the end of the linked list.
**My code so far is:**

```
void IntList::endInsert(int the_number)
{
    if (head == NULL)//if list is empty
    {
        head = new IntNode; //create new dynamic variable
        head -> data = the_number; //add value to new variable
        head -> link = NULL; 
    }
    else
    {
        NodePtr temp = head; //initialize
        //Now we want to insert in the back of list. Use for loop to get to the last element of list
        for(temp = head; temp-> link != NULL ; temp = temp -> link)
        {
            temp->link = new IntNode; //create a new var
            temp = temp ->link; //give it a "position"
            temp ->data = the_number; //Give it a value
            temp ->link = NULL;  //The new variable will be the last element and therefore points to NULL
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason it's not working :( . Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(temp = head; temp->link != NULL ; temp = temp->link);

// now temp is the last one

temp->link = new IntNode;
temp = temp->link;
temp->data = the_number;
temp->link = NULL;
```

Notice the `;` at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Well that works now :). Thank you! Why does there have to be a semicolon after the for loop in this instance?

Comment: A semicolon in this case is considered as empty block of code, like: `for(...){ /* do nothing */ }` because the `temp = temp->link` is already sufficient, you don't need do do anything else in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When list in not empty, In `for()` should loop till last node and then a new node is created and attached as below,

```
for(temp = head; temp-> link != NULL ; temp = temp -> link) ; // at the end you 
                                                                are at last node
        // Now form a link from last node to newly created one
        temp->link = new IntNode; 
        temp = temp ->link; 
        temp ->data = the_number; 
        temp ->link = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code

```
else
{
    NodePtr temp = head; //initialize
    //Now we want to insert in the back of list. Use for loop to get to the last element of list
    for(temp = head; temp-> link != NULL ; temp = temp -> link)
    {
        temp->link = new IntNode; //create a new var
        temp = temp ->link; //give it a "position"
        temp ->data = the_number; //Give it a value
        temp ->link = NULL;  //The new variable will be the last element and therefore points to NULL
    }
}
```

to the following

```
else
{
    NodePtr temp = head; //initialize
    //Now we want to insert in the back of list. Use for loop to get to the last element of list
    while ( temp-> link != NULL ) temp = temp -> link;

    temp->link = new IntNode;
    temp->link->link = NULL;
    temp->link->data = the_number; //Give it a value
}
```